# SwiftUI .onDelete of List view Crashes App

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui, macos-catalina

I have a fairly straight forward app built with SwiftUI that is essentially a master 
detail type. The data is stored in Core Data. Adding and updating records work fine,
but the app always crashes when deleting an item from the list view. I am using the 
.onDelete modifier to do the deletion. I don't receive any error messages - just the
thread breaking. The record is indeed deleted, so I'm guessing that the re-rendering
of the list view is not receiving updated data.

I may be dreaming, but I'm pretty sure that the delete function worked in the previous
two Betas. The app only runs on a device. It will not work in preview nor the simulator.

iOS 13.1, Xcode (11392r), Catalina (19A546d)

Here's the ContentView():

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDoItems()) var toDoItems: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

    @State private var newToDoItem = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                 Section(header: Text("Records")) {
                    ForEach(self.toDoItems) { toDoItem in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditToDo(toDoItem: toDoItem)) {
                            ToDoItemView(title: toDoItem.title!,
                                         firstName: toDoItem.firstName!,
                                         lastName: toDoItem.lastName!,
                                         //createdAt: "\(toDoItem.createdAt!)")
                                createdAt: self.localTimeString(date: toDoItem.createdAt!)
                                        )
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        let deleteItem = self.toDoItems[indexSet.first!]
                        self.managedObjectContext.delete(deleteItem)

                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    .onMove(perform: move)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Customers")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        print("this is the move method with no actions")
    }

    func localTimeString(date: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = .current
        formatter.dateFormat = "M-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        let returnString = formatter.string(from: date)
        return returnString
    }//localTimeString

}
```

And the managedObject:

```
public class ToDoItem : NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var createdAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String?
}

extension ToDoItem {

    static func getAllToDoItems() -> NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem> = ToDoItem.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem>
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return request
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Quick thought? Move your closure code into a function and call it with `onDelete`. After moving the code, comment *all* of it out and re-introduce it (where possible) one line at a time. See if you can narrow things down a bit.

Comment: I do have a print statement in the do block after the context save, it always prints. I have breakpoints at Section &ForEach lines. I do reach those after a delete, but not much information on the reason for the thread failure. It is Thread 1, the main and the AppDelegate breakpoint says exc_breakpoint (code=1,subcode...) which I thought indicated an attempt to unwrap an optional but that would not be an issue unless the ContentView were not querying Core Data after the deletion. There's a thought, maybe the @FetchRequest still has bugs. I'll try forcing a re-fetch after the delete.

Comment: I have a problematic list (driven from an external SQL DB) that loads at .onAppear time. I frequently get a crash with the internal tableview being out of sync with the data. Reading elsewhere, someone suggested that there are timing issues with Lists in Xcode beta 6/7. I added a tiny delay `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01)` and the list works perfectly now.

Comment: Interesting. I don't see how that can be done in a SwiftUI view?

Comment: I put the delay in the SwiftUI List View's onAppear closure. You should be able to do the same directly in the onDelete closure just after you save the managedContext - of course, just a workaround assuming this is a List bug in the beta.

Comment: Or more likely, put all of the code you have in the `onDelete` in the delayed closure. I know that my situation is different but there is a timing issue with Lists in current builds.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately that does not work for my situation. I'm pretty sure the deletion process works - it is the next screen update that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems hard to believe, but apparently the naming of an attribute in the entity as "id" is the cause of this behavior. I changed the name of the UUID attribute to "myID" and the deletions now work. I updated Xcode to GM seed 2 before making the change (the crash still happened in GM2 before renaming). The list view still does not work at all in the preview, but it does now work in the simulator and with a device.

Comment: The same behaviour is still present in XCode12 / BigSur.  Deleting on iOS worked, but the same code on macOS crashed.